# Creating a transformation matrix with respect to given bases?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Let's say I have a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, along with some bases $\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ of each respectively.

Let's say all the information I have about the transformation and vector spaces is this plus the image of $v_1$ and $v_2$ under $T$, and I want to model this in mathematica and get a transformation matrix with respect to these bases. What is the best way to do this?

So in particular I don't know in what way $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ are written in terms of the basis vectors of $W$ yet. Is there a simple way to get this with Mathematica?

---

For example, given
$$\{w_1=u_1+u_2+u_3,w_2=u_1-3u_2,w_3=4u_1+3u_2-u_3\},$$
$T(v_1) = u_1$, and $T(v_2) = u_2$, how do we make *Mathematica* write an arbitrary combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ in terms of the $w_i$'s?

Comment: What does it mean to know the image of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ but *not* know how to write them in terms of the $w$'s?

Comment: What kind of vector spaces are `V,W` are they subspaces of `R^n` for some dimension `n`, or are you trying to work in a more general vector space?

Comment: @JJM they're more general

Comment: @march let's say my basis for $W$ was $\{w_1=u_1+u_2+u_3,w2=u_1-3u_2,w_3=4u_1+3u_2-u_3\}$. And I may know that $T(v_1)=u_1$, $T(v_2)=u_2$. Then I want to work out how to make mathematica write $T(v_1)$ in terms of my elements $w_i$.

Comment: If $W$ is not an orthonormal basis, you first need to normalize it use the Gram-Schimdt process defined using the inner product of your vector space.  If the new basis elements are $\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\omega_{3}$ then the coefficients of the linear combination are simply the inner products of $T(v_{1})$ with the each of the new basis vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the sets of vectors $\{v_1,v_2\}$, $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$, and $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ are bases for their respective spaces, finding the transformation matrix is straight-forward.

Given the transformation

```
v[1] -> u[1]
v[2] -> u[2]
```

where

```
{w[1] == u[1] + u[2] + u[3], w[2] == u[1] - 3 u[2], w[3] == 4 u[1] + 3 u[2] - u[3]}
```

we first construct the matrix of `t` with respect to the `v` and `u` bases via

```
(t[u, v] = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {3, 2}] // Normal) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then, we construct the change-of basis matrix that takes us from `u` to `w`. First, solving for `u` in terms of `w`:

```
sols = Array[u, 3] /. First@Solve[
     {w[1] == u[1] + u[2] + u[3], w[2] == u[1] - 3 u[2], w[3] == 4 u[1] + 3 u[2] - u[3]},
     Array[u, 3]
   ] // Expand
```

and using this to get the basis transformation

```
(x[w, u] = Last@CoefficientArrays[sols, Array[w, 3]] // Normal) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Finally, the matrix of `t` with respect to the `v` and `w` bases is

```
(t[w, v] = x[w, u].t[u, v]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note, for instance, that this works correctly. $T(v_1)$ corresponds to

```
t[w, v].{1, 0}
(* {3/19, 1/19, 15/19} *)
```

and note that that output is exactly `u[1]` in the `w` basis.

In general, given an arbitrary vector in the space $V$, we do the following:

```
vec = a[1] v[1] + a[2] v[2];
col = Normal@Last@CoefficientArrays[vec, Array[v, 2]]
(* {a[1], a[2]} *)
```

Then,

```
row = t[w, v].col
(* {(3 a[1])/19 + (4 a[2])/19, a[1]/19 - (5 a[2])/19, (15 a[1])/19 + a[2]/19} *)
```

and finally,

```
Apply[Plus, Array[w, 3] row]
```

[image]

Comment: @mathers101. I've done things this way because I'm not sure *exactly* what format you want things in. Do you just want the matrix of $T$? Do you want something like that last result? In which case we can short-circuit the matrix formulation.

Comment: this is really great and helpful how it is. Thanks.